# How to play media files (3GP/swf files) locally inside webview

Tags: android

Iam looking for playing media files inside webview Can you please help me out ..what iam missing..I loaded webview as : `_webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3gp.html");` and the code inside my html file is as:

```
<body>
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="sample.3gp">
<embed src="file:///android_asset/sample.3gp" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
</body>.
```

Iam not getting the output. Please hellp me out ..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play SWF files you have to enable plugins:

```
_webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

and if your .html file uses javascript:

```
_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

*EDIT to answer comment*

In your situation you need to use your own webview at the moment links are redirecting to the browser:

```
 _webview.setWebViewClient(new DownloadWebViewClient());

 public class DownloadWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false; // Allows your webview to handle clicked links                
    }
 }
```

Comment: I kept sample.swf file in asset folder and am trying to run that file inside browser but am gettin blank screen..Can anyone help me. I have a code like:                                                            _linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        _webview = new WebView(this);
  _linearLayout.addView(_webview);
  setContentView(_linearLayout);  
        _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  _webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
  _webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  String url ="file:///android_asset/sample.swf";
  _webview.loadUrl(url);