# Playing .swf file in MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, flash, media-player

I'm having some issues in playing .swf files on my application.
On my PC, using Media Player Classic, they work normally, but on my phone they dont, all I hear is weird sounds.. the code I use to play:

```
mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), Uri.parse(CurrentAyaSoundPath));
```

Can anyone tell me why I cant play .swf files normally? Is there another way to play them?

Edit1: the .swf are sound only.. no video

Comment: I think you need to embed swf player in you app.

Comment: @Ahsan Rathod  How can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read these posts:

[Playing a Flash File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887758/playing-a-flash-file-in-android)

[is it possible to play .swf file and .flv files in android?? if yes then please provide code for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569187/is-it-possible-to-play-swf-file-and-flv-files-in-android-if-yes-then-please-p)

[How to play media files (3GP/swf files) locally inside webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109753/how-to-play-media-files-3gp-swf-files-locally-inside-webview)

hope it will help you